# Implement UIPageControl vertical scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I am trying to create a `UIPageControl` with vertical scrolling . By default you can slide only in horizontal direction ,but how can I slide it up to down ?

[image]

here is my code :

```
#pragma mark page control setup

- (void)setupPageScroll {
    _pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI /2 );
    _pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    _pageControl.numberOfPages = 3;
    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * _pageControl.numberOfPages, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    _scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self createPageWithView:_tower1 forPage:0];
    [self createPageWithView:_tower2 forPage:1];
    [self createPageWithView:_tower3 forPage:2];
}

- (void)createPageWithView:(UIView *)iview forPage:(int)page
{
    UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                       CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width * page, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [newView addSubview:iview];
    [_scrollView addSubview:newView];
}

- (IBAction)pageChanged:(id)sender {
    CGRect pageRect = CGRectMake(_pageControl.currentPage * _scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [_scrollView scrollRectToVisible: pageRect animated: YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) sView
{
    CGFloat offset = _scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    CGFloat pageSize = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((offset + (pageSize/2)) / pageSize);
    _pageControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've done it.  Basically, you rotate it 90 degrees as you have: `pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);`  What, specifically, is the problem you are trying to solve with your implementation?

Comment: @wottle , by default you slide page control in horizontal ,  up to down or vertical , it's all about vertical sliding and scrolling not UIPageControl rotation  !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are using interface builder, just set this value as a User Defined Runtime Atrribute.
It works.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxWSU.png

Comment: NO ! you did not understand my question !!!! I made the object vertical by this code :`_pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI /2 );` by default you slide page control in horizontal , up to down or vertical , it's all about vertical sliding and scrolling not UIPageControl rotation !!!

Comment: `UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                       CGRectMake(0, _scrollView.frame.size.height * page, _scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];

    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height * (page + 1));`

Comment: Should count yourself lucky to get a response after that inconsiderate reply @McLover Szy took the time to answer (he was the only one) and you yell at him